# How can i return a value from an overridden method in the superclass AND the method in the subclass?

Tags: java, overriding

I realized I had this issue when i was typing down simple code to find the perimeter and rectangle to demonstrate method overriding in java. can i return the area (length * breadth) in the same subclass method?

```
package override;

class perimeter{
int length,breadth;

perimeter(){length = breadth = 0;}//default constructor

perimeter(int length, int breadth){
this.length = length;
this.breadth = breadth;
}

int show(int length, int breadth){
    return 2*(length + breadth);
}
}

class area extends perimeter{
area(int length, int breadth){
    super(length,breadth);

}


int show(int length, int breadth){
    return super.show(length, breadth);
    // how can i return this too? :  return length * breadth;
}

}

public class overrideshapes {
public static void main(String args[]){
    area shape1 = new area(5,10);
    System.out.println(""+ shape1.show(shape1.length,shape1.breadth));


}

}
```

Comment: You can't, and what you want to do makes no sense. Why is `area` extending `perimeter`? Areas are not perimeters. (Also, it's convention for class names to be Pascal-case: `Area`, `Perimeter`, `OverrideShapes`)

Comment: Yeah. area can't possibly extend perimeters . but the program was just to demonstrate method overriding. However, i did find the solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do, but I'm going to explain a few more what I'm thinking about your question.

I think you want to calculate perimeter and areas for different polygons, so the best way is to create an Interface, something like this.

```
public Interface Calculate {
    public int calculateArea(int length, int width);
}
```

Then you should to implement your interface, in many clase according your polygons, for example:

```
public class Square implements Calculate {

    @Override
    public int calculateArea(int length, int width){
        return length*width; //Because this is the way you calculate square areas
    }
}
```

So you have to implement for your polygons your interface method "calculateArea" using @Override annotation, so each polygon knows how to calculate its area.

Hope it helps to you.